# Inline form template/theme rendering where declared

Tags: twig

I have this simple form where I need a custom template for a field to render something right next to the `<input>` tag. Since I won't be needing this anywhere else, I thought I'd put it right in the same template as the form like suggested [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#method-1-inside-the-same-template-as-the-form):

```
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block text_widget %}
  {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
  something
{% endblock %}

{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}
```

That's pretty much the whole template (to be used with ajax, hence no surrounding markup).

The issue now is, "something" gets rendered right at the beginning of the output where the block `text_widget` is declared, as would any other block. Its rendered fine in the form next to the `<input>`:

```
  something

<form name="form" method="post" action="">
<table id="form"><tr>
        <td>                <label for="form_Search" class="required">Search</label></td>
        <td>  <input type="text" id="form_Search" name="form[Search]" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
  something
</td>
    </tr><tr style="display: none">
        <td colspan="2"><input type="hidden" id="form__token" name="form[_token]" value="dUwdoiz9vo1TJTRjvyUcz9Rwd-D7pTvqUH-R0zCtg28" /></td>
    </tr></table>
</form>
```

This obviously makes inline theming completely unusable, so I think I might be doing something wrong...

How do I get rid of that extra "something" at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having the question already written up and also solved the problem, I might as well answer:

The solution is to derive the template from a dummy base template to swallow any output that's outside of blocks defined in the base template:

```
{# empty.html.twig #}
{% block content %}
{% endblock %}
```

And for the actually needed template:

```
{% extends 'empty.html.twig' %}
{% form_theme form _self %}
{% block text_widget %}
  {{ block('form_widget_simple') }}
  something
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  {{ form_start(form) }}
  {{ form_widget(form) }}
  {{ form_end(form) }}
{% endblock %}
```

One probably wouldn't think twice about it when customizing a field in a regular template that already uses inheritance, but this way it feels like a hack...